# Standard symbol to denote a circular sector

Tags: geometry, notation, euclidean-geometry

To denote a triangle we write $\triangle ABC$.
How about a circular sector with $O$ at the center of the circle and with the arc $AB$.
Is there a standard way such as $\lhd OAB$ where $\lhd$ has a round end?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96680/a-better-notation-to-denote-arcs-for-an-american-high-school-textbook

Comment: I'd like to see a symbol for non-meansurable sets.

Comment: I don't know of a standard symbol for this. [This TeX.SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/310384) notes that Unicode's "sector" symbol `U+2314`: ⌔ . Answers note comparable TeX symbols found in add-on packages; in particular `\downslice` in `MnSymbol`. That package also includes `\leftslice`. You might find other alternatives in [The Comprehensive $\LaTeX$ Symbol List](https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). You could also try [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html); my scribbles only yield `\sphericalangle`, which isn't quite right.

Answer (score 0):

I use [image]

as in [image]OAB.  I don't know if LaTeX has a command for it - I just made it as an image and scale it to whatever size is needed for text in a given document.